# Convert any input DDS into another DDS format in DirectXTex

Tags: c++, directx, dds-format, directxtk

I want to create a function to convert the input dds file to another format (also *DDS*)
function signature will be like this

```cpp
std::vector<byte> ConvertDDS(const byte* src, const size_t src_len, const DXGI_FORMAT format)
```

in here `src` will be a pointer to the dds file content *(full dds)*, and `format` will be the format that we want to convert the `src` into, the function return a vector of bytes that hold the converted dds.
as I said before the input *DDS* can be any format (I mean not any, but we better guess that it will be any) it can be *compressed* or *uncompressed* so we need to handle these two cases as well
What would be the right and correct way to write this function?
Currently I have this code, it *will* convert the dds, but the result aren't what I except them to be:

- first of all most of the input dds have *transparent background* but this method can't keep it and will replace the background with just white
- second the converted texture will only have one alpha channel that bically make the whole texture useless

Here is a working example of my current code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <DirectXTex.h>

void throw_error(std::string err, HRESULT hr)
{
    LPWSTR errorText = nullptr;
    DWORD messageLength = FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        nullptr, hr & 0x0000FFFF, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPWSTR)&errorText, 0, nullptr);
    if (messageLength > 0)
    {
        std::wstring wErrorText(errorText);
        std::string errorString(wErrorText.begin(), wErrorText.end());
        LocalFree(errorText);
        throw std::invalid_argument(err + ": " + errorString);
    }
}

std::vector<byte> ConvertDDS(const byte* src, const size_t src_len, const DXGI_FORMAT format)
{
    DirectX::TEX_FILTER_FLAGS dwFilter = DirectX::TEX_FILTER_DEFAULT;
    DirectX::TEX_FILTER_FLAGS dwSRGB = DirectX::TEX_FILTER_DEFAULT;
    DirectX::TEX_FILTER_FLAGS dwConvert = DirectX::TEX_FILTER_DEFAULT;
    DirectX::TEX_FILTER_FLAGS dwFilterOpts = DirectX::TEX_FILTER_DEFAULT;
    DirectX::TexMetadata meta;

    // Initialize COM (needed for WIC)
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw_error("Failed to initialize COM", hr);

    std::unique_ptr<DirectX::ScratchImage> image(new (std::nothrow) DirectX::ScratchImage);
    // load texture from memory, supported types are DDS, PNG and TGA
    hr = DirectX::LoadFromDDSMemory(src, src_len, DirectX::DDS_FLAGS_ALLOW_LARGE_FILES, &meta, *image);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw_error("Can't load texture from memory", hr);

    // If format doesn't match convert it
    if (meta.format != format)
    {
        // --- Planar ------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (DirectX::IsPlanar(meta.format))
        {
            auto img = image->GetImage(0, 0, 0);
            assert(img);
            const size_t nimg = image->GetImageCount();

            std::unique_ptr<DirectX::ScratchImage> timage(new (std::nothrow) DirectX::ScratchImage);

            hr = ConvertToSinglePlane(img, nimg, meta, *timage);
            if (FAILED(hr))
                throw_error(" FAILED [converttosingleplane]", hr);

            auto& tinfo = timage->GetMetadata();

            meta.format = tinfo.format;

            assert(meta.width == tinfo.width);
            assert(meta.height == tinfo.height);
            assert(meta.depth == tinfo.depth);
            assert(meta.arraySize == tinfo.arraySize);
            assert(meta.mipLevels == tinfo.mipLevels);
            assert(meta.miscFlags == tinfo.miscFlags);
            assert(meta.dimension == tinfo.dimension);

            image.swap(timage);
        }

        // --- Decompress --------------------------------------------------------------
        if (DirectX::IsCompressed(meta.format))
        {
            std::unique_ptr<DirectX::ScratchImage> nimage(new (std::nothrow) DirectX::ScratchImage);
            hr = DirectX::Decompress(
                image->GetImages(),
                image->GetImageCount(),
                meta,
                DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN,
                *nimage
            );
            if (FAILED(hr))
                throw_error("Can't decompress dds texture", hr); // decompress new texture failed
            meta.format = nimage->GetMetadata().format;
            image.swap(nimage);
        }

        if (meta.format != format)
        {
            // If the original file is compressed we compress the src
            // Else we just convert it
            if (DirectX::IsCompressed(format))
            {
                std::unique_ptr<DirectX::ScratchImage> nimage(new (std::nothrow) DirectX::ScratchImage);
                hr = DirectX::Compress(
                    image->GetImages(),
                    image->GetImageCount(),
                    meta,
                    format,
                    DirectX::TEX_COMPRESS_FLAGS::TEX_COMPRESS_DEFAULT,
                    DirectX::TEX_THRESHOLD_DEFAULT,
                    *nimage
                );
                if (FAILED(hr))
                    throw_error("Can't compress dds texture", hr); // convert new texture failed
                image.swap(nimage);
            }
            else
            {
                std::unique_ptr<DirectX::ScratchImage> nimage(new (std::nothrow) DirectX::ScratchImage);
                hr = DirectX::Convert(
                    image->GetImages(),
                    image->GetImageCount(),
                    meta,
                    format,
                    dwFilter | dwFilterOpts | dwSRGB | dwConvert,
                    DirectX::TEX_THRESHOLD_DEFAULT,
                    *nimage
                );
                if (FAILED(hr))
                    throw_error("Can't convert dds texture", hr); // convert new texture failed
                image.swap(nimage);
            }
            meta.format = image->GetMetadata().format;
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<DirectX::Blob> blob(new (std::nothrow) DirectX::Blob);
    DirectX::SaveToDDSMemory(
        image->GetImages(),
        image->GetImageCount(),
        image->GetMetadata(),
        DirectX::DDS_FLAGS_NONE,
        *blob.get()
    );
    std::vector<byte> result(blob->GetBufferSize());
    std::memcpy(result.data(), blob->GetBufferPointer(), blob->GetBufferSize());
    return result;
}
```

this code does seem to be working, but output as I said dont have the *transparent* background and overall looks wrong... what should I do? I'm not very familer with DirectXTex API so I will be happy if someone can help me.

I tried to convert a DDS texture with format `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` to `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM` but failed.
input had transparency but output only had a white background
the content of the texture also were wrong after conversation.

Comment: A few minor comments: First, you should only need to call ``CoInitializeEx`` once (maybe once per thread) rather than doing it in every invocation of the function.  Second, you are using ``(std::nothrow)`` for all the memory allocations, but relying on throws for error handling so you should remove it to out-of-memory is thrown as normal.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn thank you, yes you are right, I copied parts of this code from *texconv* program, the way that it handle error is different from me, so yeah I better remove `(std::nothrow)`. about calling `CoInitializeEx` in each function call, it should be ok in my case, because currently I use this function once per program lifetime anyway...

Answer (score 4):

What behavior do you want for going from `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` to `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM`?

The default behavior for an RGB to R conversion is to use luminance to convert the RGB to a greyscale and store that in the RED channel. There's no place to put a transparency channel in the target.

Are you expecting the alpha channel to 'mask' the image here? If so, what's the 'background color'?

If you want to keep the alpha channel you'd need to use `DXGI_FORMAT_R8A8_UNORM`.

> DirectXTex does support other ways of mapping the channels. You can do channel swizzles, or you can use flags like `TEX_FILTER_RGB_COPY_RED`, `TEX_FILTER_RGB_COPY_GREEN`, or `TEX_FILTER_RGB_COPY_BLUE`. See [Filter flags](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Filter-Flags).

For examples of doing arbitrary channel swizzles, see [texconv](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/main/Texconv/texconv.cpp#LL2530).

Comment: thank you, but how can I handle all these cases for all types of input files? I mean take this [texture.dds](https://file.io/ku1sSMJKGuZj) for example as you can see seems like its only have one alpha channel that store all the glyphs, how can I convert from other formats to this?